# iOS WeChat SDK Login Integration issue : System error. Error code:10026

Tags: ios, wechat, wechat-auth

I am implementing login with WeChat functionality using WeChat iOS SDK.
I do i have WeChat developer id(appID).
i have done following coding in iOS app

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [WXApi registerApp:@"APP_ID"];


    return YES;
}
```

When i call senAuthReq like this

```
-(void)sendAuthRequest{
    SendAuthReq* req = [[SendAuthReq alloc ] init] ;
    req.scope = @"snsapi_userinfo" ;
    req.state = @"123" ;

    [WXApi sendReq:req];
}
```

WeChat iOS app Gives me error:
**Unable to log in WeChat.
System error. Error code:10026**

Answer (score 1):

Check your APP bundleID on the WeChat at Wechat'OpenPlatForm, keep it same with yours

Comment: please add example to your answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: I am using WeChat official account for login integration. Everything works fine with Open platform but not with WeChat Official account.